# How to get an array of sentences using CFStringTokenizer?

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, cfstring

I've created an string tokenizer like this:

```
stringTokenizer = CFStringTokenizerCreate(
                         NULL
                         , (CFStringRef)str
                         , CFRangeMake(0, [str length])
                         , kCFStringTokenizerUnitSentence
                         , userLocale);
```

But how do I obtain those sentences now from the tokenizer? The CF String Programming Guide doesn't mention `CFStringTokenizer` or tokens (did a full-text search in the PDF).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is an example of [CFStringTokenizer](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFStringTokenizerRef/Reference/reference.html) usage:

```
CFStringRef string; // Get string from somewhere
CFLocaleRef locale = CFLocaleCopyCurrent();

CFStringTokenizerRef tokenizer = 
    CFStringTokenizerCreate(
        kCFAllocatorDefault
        , string
        , CFRangeMake(0, CFStringGetLength(string))
        , kCFStringTokenizerUnitSentence
        , locale);

CFStringTokenizerTokenType tokenType = kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone;
unsigned tokensFound = 0;

while(kCFStringTokenizerTokenNone !=
    (tokenType = CFStringTokenizerAdvanceToNextToken(tokenizer))) {
    CFRange tokenRange = CFStringTokenizerGetCurrentTokenRange(tokenizer);
    CFStringRef tokenValue =
        CFStringCreateWithSubstring(
            kCFAllocatorDefault
            , string
            , tokenRange);

  // Do something with the token
  CFShow(tokenValue);
  CFRelease(tokenValue);
  ++tokensFound;
}

// Clean up
CFRelease(tokenizer);
CFRelease(locale);
```

Comment: +1. It's also possible to do the same using the higher level `[NSString enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:]` with the option `NSStringEnumerationBySentences`, though the Foundation solution is a little more powerful. For example, you can specify any locale using `CFStringTokenizerCreate`, whereas `enumerateSubstringsInRange:options:usingBlock:` uses the current user locale.

Answer (score 0):

You may also use:

```
    [mutstri enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [mutstri length])
                                options:NSStringEnumerationBySentences
                             usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop){

                                 NSLog(@"%@", substring);

                             }];
```